# What is the name of the "run command" program?

Tags: gnome, execute-command

What is the name of the program that is invoked when `Alt+F2` is pressed, in Gnome?

The grey dialog box presented here, where you can type in the command/program you want to run:

[image]

from this [article on the Alt+F2 shortcut](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/alt-f2-ultimate-linux-keyboard-shortcut/); what is the name of the executable file that runs this?

Comment: I am guessing it is not a separate program but it is a part of the gnome shell. That is, it is built into the desktop GUI.

Comment: You can see which "shell" the Gnome prompt invokes by typing `echo $SHELL` into the box.

Comment: @waltinator not the shell — the command for creating/running the pop up dialog into which you type in a command name.

Comment: Why did you now include a screenshot of what probably is KDE desktop if you indicate "Gnome" in your question?

Comment: @Dave If you want and executable to do something like that **"pop-up box to run commands"** then probably you'll like `gmrun` install it by `sudo apt install gmrun`

Answer (score 4):

It is not a separate program. It is a part of Gnome Shell, not quite consistently referred to as the "command dialog" or the "Alt+F2 prompt" in the official [Gnome Shell documentation](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/CheatSheet#Developer_tools).

The javascript code for that part of Gnome Shell can be seen [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/blob/main/js/ui/runDialog.js#L18) (Thanks to user Raffa for providing the link).

Comment: From linked documenttion "Looking Glass is GNOME Shell's integrated inspector tool and JavaScript console useful for debugging. It can be run by typing 'lg' in the Alt+F2 prompt and can then be exited by pressing Esc. More details are here.
Looking Glass"  -- What is the program that is invoked by the first Alt+F2, the one where you were supposed to type "lg"?

Comment: @Dave not to sound like a broken record, but there isn't a separate program for that. It's part of the GNOME Shell, just like this looking glass tool is, just like the activities overview, workspaces, panel, etc.

Comment: Somehow I didn't see your answer until I posted mine then deleted it ... **+1** ... It's not "a program" ... It's just JavaScript code that is executed within the gnome-shell itself. It executes Gnome Shells special commands like `r` internally and runs the rest of the commands in the default terminal ... see [source](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/blob/main/js/ui/runDialog.js)